# Sequelize findAll() produces valid query with no results

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Attempting to run a query that returns 'composeID' from the table 'Interactions' sequelize is able to produce valid SQL that returns a result but does not return anything to the application.

```js
console.log(await Interactions.findAll({
            attributes: ['composeID'],
            include: 
                [{
                    model: User,
                    where: {id: id},
                    attributes: []
                }],
                order: [
                    ['composeID', 'ASC']
                ],
                raw: true
        }))
```

In the terminal the output is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `username`, `passwordSalt`, `passwordHash`, `isGithub`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `deletedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `User`.`username` LIKE '%test_user%') LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): SELECT `Interactions`.`composeID` FROM `Interactions` AS `Interactions` INNER JOIN `Users` AS `User` ON `Interactions`.`UserId` = `User`.`id` AND (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `User`.`id` = 1) ORDER BY `Interactions`.`composeID` ASC;
[]
```

When run in sql as

```sql
SELECT
  `Interactions`.`composeID`
FROM
  `Interactions` AS `Interactions`
  INNER JOIN `Users` AS `User` ON `Interactions`.`UserId` = `User`.`id`
  AND (
    `User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
    AND `User`.`id` = 1
  )
ORDER BY
  `Interactions`.`composeID` ASC;
```

The following is produced:

| composeID |
| --- |
| (NULL) |
| 63f2d6d734310cd44e408dee |

I feel like it is unexpected behavior for a valid sql query with results to return '[]'. Is there something I am missing or improperly running in my code? I am trying to use the ORM to its full capabilities and am trying to avoid running a raw SQL query. I have attempted this solution using both `raw: true` and without `raw: true` with both returning an empty array.

Comment: What do you get if you console `JSON.stringify(queryResult, null, 2)`?

Comment: @PrerakSola running JSON.stringify(queryResult, null, 2) also returns `[]`

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct db?

Comment: @PrerakSola It seems like I am due to all other queries working in the application and the initialization script showing the proper tables on application start without error

Comment: Without `required: true` in the includes object, it should do an `outer join`. Not sure why it is doing an `inner join` on users table. Ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#required-eager-loading

Comment: @PrerakSola INNER JOIN is becuase `where` option in `include`

Comment: Try to execute generated query in `sequelize.query` with `type: QueryTypes.SELECT`

Comment: @Anatoly running 

const rawQuery = await Interactions.sequelize.query(
            'SELECT...',
            {type: QueryTypes.SELECT}
        )

Also returns `[]` - but the query is still valid when running directly in SQL

Comment: Then the only reason could be a different DB

Comment: @Anatoly I am able to create new rows to both tables using the same sequelize connection so I do not believe so

Comment: Not sure what your issue is here, but your first block of SQL can't have been generated by the Sequelize code above it. At least not the first of the two lines.  Nothing in your code would generate anything like "`User`.`username` LIKE '%test_user%') LIMIT 1"

Comment: Also not sure, but I believe you need to include `id` in the `attributes` list for this to work? Not sure; seems to me I've had something like this in the past and that was the solution. good luck.